# Expectation using integral identity

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $X$ be a positive random variable. Then $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{t=0}^{\infty}P(X>t)dt$. For any positive constant $a$ and $b$, suppose we have $P(X>\sqrt{a+u}+b+u)\leq 2e^{-u}$ for all $u$. Intuitively, it seems $\mathbb{E}[X]$ should be at most $c(\sqrt{a+1}+b+1)$ for some constant $c$. How do I formally show it integral identity?

Comment: Have you tried the change of variables $t  = \sqrt{a+u}+b+u$? I had a go and it is messy but it seems like the place to start.

Comment: I don't understand the role of $a,b$ in this question: since the probability cannot increase as $a$ and $b$ increase, just set them both to zero.   Now you merely need show $E[X]$ is finite, which is easy.

Comment: @whuber: I'm confident that you're correct but what's the argument that one would use for doing that since the question says for any positive constants a and b ? thanks.

Comment: Use $\Pr(X\gt \sqrt{u}+u)=\lim_{a,b\to 0^{+}}\Pr(X\gt\sqrt{a+u}+b+u)\le\lim_{a,b\to 0^+}2e^{-u}=2e^{-u}.$

Comment: nice. so I also didn't need the relation right at the top to get $u$ alone. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\sqrt{(x + y)} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$, to get $u$ alone.

Argument is that, since $P\left(X > (\sqrt{(a + u)} + b + u)\right) \leq 2 e^{-u}$, then relation above implies that

$P\left(X > \left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{u} + b + u\right)\right) \leq 2 e^{-u}$

Rewriting this slightly gives

$P\left(X > \left(\sqrt{u} + u + \sqrt{a} + b\right)\right) \leq  2 e^{-u}$

Now, I'm doing a wave of hands here but am pretty certain that  a limiting argument can be used to eliminate $a$ and $b$ since the relation holds for any positive constants $a$ and $b$ ( basically make $a$ and $b$ teeny positive constants that approach zero ).

Removing $a$ and $b$ then allows you to use the expectation relation for positive random variables but substitute $(\sqrt{u} + u)$ for $t$.

$E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X > u + \sqrt{u}) ~du$

But the expectation relation now becomes less than or equals since the probability statement is not an equality but rather a less than or equals.

$E(X) \leq \int_{0}^\infty (2\times e^{-u} ~du)$

NOTE: Evaluation of integral needs to use the jacobian the details which are spelled out in the comments below the answer. So, the answer below is not correct.

Evaluating the integral results in:

$E(X) \leq -2 e^{-u} ]_{0}^{\infty} = 2$

So, an upper bound for $E(X)$ is 2. Maybe there's a way to get an equality but I don't see it.

Comment: Can you please explain the step "but the expectation relation now becomes less than or equal... ". Thank you.

Comment: Hi: The $P(X > t)$ statement in the expectation should be equal to something right. But, in this case, we only have a less than or equals rather than an equals. So, the expectation goes from equality to less than or equals. But I think I have a mistake because one needs the jacobian to evaluate $P( X > u + \sqrt{u})$. Can you fix that part ? We need a new variable say $g = u + \sqrt{u}$ and then a substitution like the original comment mentioned. So, we need $dg = du(1 + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{u}}) $.

Comment: Right, but I can not get it all work out in terms of $g$. So we have $\int_0^{\infty}P(X>g)dg=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>u+\sqrt{u})(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}})du\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}2e^{-u} (1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}})du$. If we separate the terms the first term is easy how do deal with the second term $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{-u}du$? Never mind, just do another change of variable $u=x^2$.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\infty u^{-1/2} e^{-u} \, \text{d} u$ is $\Gamma (1 / 2)$ which is equal to $\sqrt\pi$ so the upper bound should be $2 + \sqrt\pi$, does that sound right?

Comment: @user40739: It seems like your seperation approach along with stephematician pointing out the gamma relation gives an interesting answer. I hope it's correct ? thanks stephematician for that input.

Comment: Thanks to both stephematician and @mlofton. Yes, $2+\sqrt{\pi}$ is the correct answer. By the way, the hand wavy argument that you did before, you can simply do $P(X-\sqrt{a}-b>u+\sqrt{u})\leq 2e^{-u}$ first, set $Y=X-\sqrt{a}-b$, find the bound on expectation of $Y$ and substitute to $X$.

Comment: thanks. you're right. no hand waving needed.

Comment: @user40739: See my comment question to whuber and his answer for a different argument which also deals with $a$ and $b$.